# Improving a search engine

Tags: search, search-engine, heuristics

I'm working on a search engine. For the most part, I'm simply using Appache's Lucene, which is working great so far, but I also wanted to improve the search results by establishing good "heuristics" within the search. (For example, if someone searches 'couch' and I have all of the couches cataloged as type 'sofa', I want the search algorithm to make the connection.)

I know this sounds a bit vague, but I don't know where to continue searching to find further reading in this study. (I Googled terms like 'heuristic search', 'heuristic function', etc, but they're not referring to the same thing I am.) So, I wanted to know if any of you guys worked on similar problems in search engines, and if you would recommend anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to build something similar for my Artificial Intelligence class.  I build a web crawler that associated synonyms of words similar to what your looking to do.  When a user searches for a term such as 'couch', I grabbed all of the synonyms of couch and stored them in a database with a reference to the original word.  When the engine gets run again and 'sofa' gets searched, the application will again grab synonyms of 'sofa' (which is a synonym of couch).  You should then be able to match that association.

There are plenty of free api's to get the synonym of a word.  Try changing your google searches to Topic Specific Web Crawlers, or Topic specific search engines.  You will gather better results

Comment: Thanks for the help tkcsam. That answers my question. If I knew how to mark questions as solved, I definitely would in this case!

Answer (score 1):

One of the "quick n' dirty" hack which is popped in my mind can be to implement a dictionary which holds similarities in context. e.g. make sofa and couch group similar. Or much better approach could be to build a square matrix to hold "similarity score" for each word pairs. Here is random matrix about what I mean:

```
        couch   sofa   chair
couch |  100  |   95 |   75  |
sofa  |   95  |  100 |   65  |
chair |   75  |   65 |  100  |
```

Another approach could be adaptively update that matrix with users selection. e.g. if a user search couch and then click chair, then you can increase couch-chair score by a defined threshold (of course, you should also renormalize all scores after each update).

Comment: That's a great idea, Osman! It sounds a little heavy for what I wanted to do, but it gave me great ideas, thanks!